# How do I use a prepopulated SQLite DB with Expo on Android?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, react-native, expo

I'm trying to use a prepopulated `SQLite` DB for my react native app. I'm using Expo and the `downloadAsync()` Function to load my DB from my assets folder. This works as expected on IOS, as I can load the DB and retrieve the data.

On Android however I just can't get this to work. The db file is there in the internal storage of my emulator, but every time I try to retrieve data, an error occurs since 'there is no such table'.

My guess is that SQLite doesn't properly search for my db but instead creates a new one, where my tables are obviously missing.

I've been trying for over 7 hours now, so I appreciate any kind of help.

Folder structure:

`App.js
-assets
--db
---db.db
-src
--connection
---connectionClass`

App.js

```
const App = () => {
    const [dbLoaded, setDbLoaded] = useState(false);   

    if(!dbLoaded){
        downloadDB().then((value) => setDbLoaded(value));
        return <></>
    } else {
        return (
            <Navigation/>
        );
    }
};
```

ConnectionClass.js

```
export const downloadDB = async () => {
    await FileSystem.deleteAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`, {idempotent : true});
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`, {intermediates: true });

    return await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        Asset.fromModule(require('../../assets/db/WaKanji.db')).uri,
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/WaKanji.db`
    ).then(({status}) => {
        if(status === 200){               
            return true
        }
        return false
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Err\n' + error);
        return false;
    });

};
```

Comment: FWIW this does not work for me in iOS. The error I get relates to not being able to use the file format even if I update my metro config to accept it.